# Php Foreach error Invalid argument

Tags: php, sql, foreach, phpmyadmin

I got this error in my foreach in php:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in...

Code:

```
$database = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=staff_tool', $user, '');
foreach ($database->query('SELECT id,firstname,lastname FROM `staff` SET categorie_bit = 0') as $testx) {
                var_dump($testx);
            }
```

Edited Code:

```
foreach ($database->query('SELECT id,firstname,lastname,categorie_bit FROM `staff` WHERE categorie_bit = 1 SET categorie_bit = 0') as $testx) {
            var_dump($testx);
        }
```

Comment: does your query return anything??

Comment: no just the warning message

Comment: Did your new PDO return anything? Because I can't see any error checking...

Comment: Odd sql? (select with set clause...)

Comment: im asking, you are passing your query result as parameter to foreach, so does your query anything . Coz, that error will come if your query result is empty.

Comment: Your query is wrong.

Comment: as said by @jarlh, change set to where, it will work

Comment: if you run the query, are you getting the result from db??

Answer (score 0):

PHP s foreach expects param one to be an array of an iterable but it seems like you are passing in a statement object(printr) will output nothing more the select statement). You might wanna try:

```
      $stmt = $db->query($sql);
       $stmt->execute();
       $results  = $stmt->fetchAll();

         foreach($results as $result)
                var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $database->query('SELECT id,firstname,lastname,categorie_bit FROM `staff` WHERE categorie_bit = 1 SET categorie_bit = 0');

// always check if you have a valid array ... you do not have any guarantees that SELECT query will return you a result set
if(is_array($result) && count($result) > 0) {
    foreach ($result as $testx) {
        var_dump($testx);
    }
}
```

Comment: tried this it goes to the else condition which I added in my code